# Android debug traces do not contain all method?

Tags: android, android-traceview

I use `Debug#startMethodTracing`(in `Activity#onCreate`) and `Debug#stopMethodTracing`(in `Activity#onWindowFocusChanged`) to get method call traces. But I can not find `ViewRootImpl#performTraversals` in trace in Monitor. What's wrong?

Comment: This question is already answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20571324/android-debug-traces-do-not-contain-application-specific-method-calls

Comment: @AliHaiderWarraich it's different